# Ant Design. How to set form field error message dynamically?

Tags: antd

A form field has many asynchronous check rules, since a composited api can check these rules one time by return different result, i do not want to fire so many api request.

Answer (score 58):

the syntax is updated in `v4`

new syntax is:

```
setFields.   |  Set fields status   |   (fields: FieldData[]) => void
```

example :

```
form.setFields([
   {
     name: 'field-to-update',
     errors: ['error-string'],
   },
]);
```

Comment: This only works if your fields are actually *mounted*.

Answer (score 36):

Use `form.setFields`

Syntax

```jsx
Function({ fieldName: { value: any, errors: Error } })
```

Example from [here](https://github.com/react-component/form/blob/3b9959b57ab30b41d8890ff30c79a7e7c383cad3/examples/server-validate.js#L74-L79) -

```jsx
this.props.form.setFields({
  user: {
    value: values.user,
    errors: [new Error('forbid ha')],
  },
});
```

Comment: The syntax should be `{ fieldName: { value: any, errors: Error[] }`

Comment: The latest type definition is: `{ fieldName: {name: NamePath, errors: string[] | undefined }`
Where `type NamePath = string | string[]`

Answer (score 10):

When you need to add a custom error message just use `validateStatus` && `help` attributes.
For example, you've got an error as loginError (string) in your props:

```tsx
<Form.Item
    { ...props.loginError && {
        help: props.loginError,
        validateStatus: 'error',
    }}>
    {getFieldDecorator('email', {
        rules: [
            { required: true, message: 'You have to write the email' },
        ],
    })(
        <Input size="large"/>,
    )}
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Awesome! I had to wrap it in parentheses in my case, which gave me the following
`<Form.Item
    name="my-input"
    label="enter something"
    {...(otherFieldRequired && {
        help: 'Please enter an input',
        validateStatus: 'error',
    })}
>`

Answer (score 1):

```
                form.setFields([
                  {
                    name: "email", // required
                    value: "myemail@@gmail.com",//optional
                    errors: ["Invalid email"],
                  },
                ]);
```

I used it in `v4.16.11`