# Custom validateStatus in Ant Design Form.Item

Tags: reactjs, antd

I would like to add a custom `validateStatus` to my Form.Item only if `result` is set in the state. If not I would like it to be generated by the validation rule:

```
<Form.Item
  name="email"
  rules={[{ required: true, type: 'email', message: 'Enter you email' }]}
  required
  validateStatus={result && (result.result === "success" ? "success" : "warning")}
  help={result && (result.result === "success" ? "You've subscribed successfully!" : "Your email is already subscribed")}
>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Here is a link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-sky-7ms8t?file=/index.js). You can see that the help message is working, but `validateStatus` doesn't seem to work, as the help message always stays grey (it should be red, when `validateStatus` is set to an error, or green, when it's set to success). How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you create it on codesandbox? [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-pasteur-dk7id) i made a sandbox and try to recreate it but seems working. I also used a dummy result variable. You can edit that and save it and include it on your question for better debugging.

Comment: @Chanandrei Hi, I've updated my question with the link to codesandbox and added some more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding `undefined` to `validateStatus`:

```
<Form.Item
  name="email"
  rules={[{ required: true, type: 'email', message: 'Enter you email' }]}
  required
  validateStatus={result ? (result.result === "success" ? "success" : "warning") : undefined}
  help={result && (result.result === "success" ? "You've subscribed successfully!" : "Your email is already subscribed")}
>
```

And some custom css `.ant-form-item-has-success .ant-form-item-explain {color: #52c41a;}` to display success message as green.

Comment: Awesome! short and nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Upon checking, there's no green border or text color if `validateStatus` prop value is `success`. I tried to place help message but no green color (I used antd documentation code). What can you do is to place `hasFeedback` prop, it will show green checked icon indication of success.

On the error side, it seems that when you include `validateStatus` prop, it forcedly removed some css selectors for the `rules` styles. This was also said on this [issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/26051). You can take a look on this class name `ant-form-item-has-error` for futher investigation.

Solution is don't include the props if the `result` is null.

```
const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

const onFinish = (values) => {
  const res = "error"; //<--- change this to see different result
  if (res === "success") {
    setResult({ result: "success" });
  } else {
    setResult({ result: "error" });
  }
};

<Form.Item
  label="Email"
  name="email"
  rules={[{ required: true, message: "Enter you email" }]}
  {...(result && {
    hasFeedback: true,
    help:
      result.result === "success"
        ? "You've subscribed successfully!"
        : "Your email is already subscribed",
    validateStatus: result.result === "success" ? "success" : "warning",
  })}
>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
```

[image: Edit prod-http-h73fi]

I suggest to pick only one idea when it comes showing form error. This can be done using `rules` props and `form` instance only and also can be done using `validateStatus` and `help` props alone.

See also this helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246396/ant-design-how-to-set-form-field-error-message-dynamically).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Though I ended up with a different solution. See my own answer below.